# Html changes not detected in watched Angular library by "ng serve --aot"

Tags: html, angular, webpack, angular-cli

**Description**

Html changes are not detected in library when starting project using ng serve --aot. Library is built using --watch flag and main project is served with --aot. On html change build and serve process are triggered and page refreshes but with no changes in html. Typescript changes are visible after rebuild. Html change is only visible when you restart ng serve --aot process.

Without --aot flag everything is working as intended.

Same problem exists with npm linked external library (not in the same project).

**Reproduction**

I made a small repro of the problem: https://github.com/V3nsla/aot-lib-html-changes

To reproduce the problem build library using --watch flag (ng build lib --watch) and start main project using ng serve --aot.

Make some changes in the template of LibComponent and save to trigger build process. After main project is recompiled html changes are not reflected.

**Environment**

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 10.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.0
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.0
@angular/cli                       7.3.0
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.0
@schematics/angular                7.3.0
@schematics/update                 0.13.0
ng-packagr                         4.7.0
rxjs                               6.3.3
typescript                         3.2.4
webpack                            4.29.0
```